# What exactly happens when you accidentally unstage GIT files on top of "changed" files?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Boy, did I screw up. I had a few files that were staged in a big project and was working all day on more changes, some of which I am sure were files that were in the "staged" area. I am in the process of restoring a backup to see if I can compare changes and get myself out of this mess. While I am waiting for the restore, it gave me time to beat myself up and ask this question.

My assumption is that whatever files were in the staged area just kiboshed (overwrote) the files in the "changes" area. Am I correct? I will keep searching/

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I panicked. Combine that with a lack of knowledge of what I had just nuked from my staging area as well as a lack of knowledge of what "unstaging" actually did, I imagined the worst.

Here's my question (and an explanation in the hopes that it helps someone else understand) as to what prompted my original question. Here was my (after-the-panic) test. I'll make an example with a text file to keep it simple.

I start with an empty file, and now add the contents: `AAAAAA`. The file shows up as "changed" in my Git changes panel.

Now I stage the file. The file moves from "changed" to "staged".

Next, I change the content: `AAAAAA,BBBBBB.`

**THIS** is where I inadvertently UNSTAGED the file (and panicked, of course) and the. The Git panel showed the file only in the changed panel, as expected, but I feared that the contents of my file would be only `AAAAAA` and that I would have no idea (in real life with a hundred changed code files) what I was missing from the code files. The GOOD news is that the contents of my example file still showed `AAAAAA,BBBBBB`. My actual code files were safe with NOTHING changed from my errant mouseclick. ONLY the indication that they were no longer "staged". Thank goodness. I can live with that.

A couple of helpful links [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37142132/1560325) and [HERE](https://crunchify.com/git-repository-what-stage-means-in-git-source-control/). And special thanks to @jthill for be patient with me and holding my hand while I panicked. ;-)

Comment: haha laughing at the memory of my own blindspotting moments, glad it was this "easy" :-/. I woke up with this nagging fear I'd missed something, led you down the garden path, which it seems I actually did, kinda. Anyway, the code I gave will show you all the interim versions that got replaced (by newer versions or by resetting to an older one).

Answer (score 1):

`git add` adds the content to the repo, it's all still in there, unstage just means wiping an index pointer to it.

```
find .git/objects/?? -type f -exec ls -t {} + | awk -F/ '{print $3$4}'
```

will list your loose objects (that's stuff you've done locally since the last repack), latest first. To whittle it down to stuff you care about,

```
find .git/objects/?? -type f -exec ls -t {} + \
| awk -F/ '{print $3$4}' | git cat-file --batch-check \
| awk '$2=="blob" && n++<50'
```

which will show the fifty most-recently `git add`ed blobs. `git show` those ids (if you've  added any media files maybe show them all through a pager to keep the binary stuff from being annoying) and put the ones you love back where they belong with

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,$thatid,the.right.name
```

to get the index pointers back and then you can `git checkout-index -a` if you want everything back in your work tree too.

Comment: Oh my -- you may just be a real life saver. You must have a PHD in git. :-) I will carefully go through your instructions and get back shortly. Thank you SOOO much. What a way to end a week! :-(

Comment: searching to find how to install 'awk' on windows - getting "'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command..." I figured that something like awk would be loaded as part of Git in Visual Studios...

Comment: used "choco install awk" in en elevated prompt to install awk (for anyone interested). but running into syntax issues now somehow. :-(

Comment: Install Git for Windows, that comes with the core utilities and basics like sed and awk and bash. I can't help you with the powershell stuff, by all evidence there's plenty of people who use it and like it fine but it simply does not play well at all with the tools I already use.

Comment: I assumed Git for Windows would have been installed with VS2019. Maybe just a subset? I will install Git for WIndows now - hopefully it will not clobber anything in VS2019 already setup... Thank you for your help @jthill

Comment: Here's hoping it winds up actually helping... <knockwood/>

Comment: haha. thanks -- i'll be careful :-) <fingers-crossed>

Comment: if you are still around - to my original question - did my "staged" files clobber my "changed" files losing changes since they were staged, or did I just lose markers, as you mentioned? I could live without the markers...

Comment: Not sure what "changed" means exactly here, `git add` snapshots the complete current content and puts in the repo and updates the index entry to point to that, that's staging. It can't alter your work tree, where you're doing your changes, and what you checked out is always retrievable from the checked-out commit's tree. I don't know what markers you're referring to, sorry, I use that word for the markers on unresolved merge conflicts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246901/discussion-between-humblebeginnings-and-jthill).